# Converting NSString of Vertice Information to a Multidimensional Array - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have a NSString of vertice information such as :

"0.943182 0.95878 0 0.853249 0.956043 0 0.795583 0.954268 0 0.738116 0.954268 0"

I need to add commas between each value, group the vertices into groups of three and then add the three values to an array (which I will then add to a multidimensional array for use with OpenGL ES).

Can anyone advise on how I can insert the commas and group the data ?

Thanks !

Comment: there are 10 numbers in the example, so the last group is only one number ?

Comment: For commas you can use [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@","]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple :

Break the string.

```
NSArray *nums = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Alloc/init a group array that will store groups.

```
NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

Loop over the components of the source string and make groups separated by `","` with them.

```
NSUInteger basetIndex = 0;
NSString *str = @"";
for(baseIndex = 0; baseIndex < [nums count]; baseIndex += 3) {
    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,%@,%@", [nums objectAtIndex:baseIndex],
                                       [nums objectAtIndex:baseIndex+1],
                                       [nums objectAtIndex:baseIndex+2]];
    [groups addObject:str];
    str = @"";
    // or str = [NSString stringWithFormat:...] and no str = @""
}
```

This code will work given a right number of numbers, you would check indexes for components in the other case.

Comment: I'm getting "instance method stringWithFormat not found" ?

Comment: Thanks corrected! stupid mistake, the previous one was a class method. Also modified slightly to get the desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Instead of first inserting commas into the string I'd rather just scan the string step by step:

```
NSString *str = @"0.943182 0.95878 0 0.853249 0.956043 0 0.795583 0.954268 0 0.738116 0.954268 0";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
typedef struct { float x, y, z; } vertex;
while (YES) {
    vertex v;
    if (! ([scanner scanFloat:&v.x] && [scanner scanFloat:&v.y] && [scanner scanFloat:&v.z]))
        break;
    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f", v.x, v.y, v.z);
    // put the vertex in some container
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

```
NSString *str  = @"0.943182 0.95878 0 0.853249 0.956043 0 0.795583 0.954268 0 0.738116 0.954268 0";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSUInteger cnt = 0;
NSMutableArray *multilist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *temp = @"";
for (NSString *comp in arr ) {

    cnt++;
    if( cnt == 3 )
    {
        cnt = 0;
        temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@" ,comp];
        [multilist addObject:temp];
        temp = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ," ,comp];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",multilist);
[multilist release];
```